# Using bilateral export flows as a proxy variable in gravity model

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, model, cross-section

I have used a gravity model (cross-section data) for my thesis and as a dependent variable, I have taken bilateral export flows which I used as a proxy to measure the risk of being exposed to a carbon policy (higher exports, higher chances to get impacted by the policy). The issue I am having is with the coefficient signs in the OLS regression. The correlation does make sense between the independent variable and dependent variable (bilateral exports) but when related to risk exposure, the interpretation is counterfactual. Is it a model misspecification issue or something else?
Let me know if any other detail needs to be provided to better understand the context.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to CV, Ida. We need *some* details at least!  All you have really told us is that you are running a regression and you don't believe your results.  We can't help you with that.  You need to describe your data and your model and give us some useful indications of how specifically the "interpretation is counterfactual."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply :)
The aim of my research is to assess the influence of country-level factors on the exposure to risk from a carbon policy. 
lnXijt = α0 +β1lnGDPit + β2lnGDPjt + β3ln_POPit +β4ln_POPjt +β5Distanceijt +β6Contiguityij + β7Languageij + β7Colonyij + β8lnRenewables_investmentij + β9 energy intensityj + β10lnREM_EXPi,t + β11lnREM_IMPj,t + εijt

Xijt - bilateral export flows (exposure to risk from the carbon border policy).

Comment: Part of right hand variables  are taken from the basic model of gravity (GDP, population, distance contiguity etc. ) + augmented with two variables that might influence the exposure to risk - investments in renewables and energy intensity. The last two variables are remoteness indexes - capture the impact of Multilateral Resistance Terms (MRTs) in the model.

Comment: Referring to counterfactual interpretation, for example, OLS regression results of this model show a positive correlation between investments in renewables and bilateral export flows (proxy variable). However, this positive correlation contradicts the expected relationship between investments in renewables and exposure to risk.  Logically, increasing investments in renewables should lead to a decrease in exposure to risk as the investments in renewables would contribute in less energy-intensive content of the exported goods.  Hope I have been able to somehow express myself!

Comment: Perhaps -- but it's difficult to piece that together in the comments.  If you wish this community to address your question, then please edit the question itself and consider using the MathJax markup to make your equations readable.